# socket.io: Share socket.id with other users

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, engine.io

I have a socket.io signaling server in which I need to allow two connected clients to discover each other and exchange information.

I am thinking about using the socket.id for this as it is the true unique value for a connection using some code like this:

```
  socket.on('patient ready', appointmentId => {
    socket.join(appointmentId, err => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      socket.to(appointmentId).emit('patient ready', socket.id)
    })
  })
```

The official documentation (e.g https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/#socket-id) says the id is the "unique identifier for the socket session". So I am concerned, can I securely broadcast the `session.id` of one user to other users or would that allow them to hijack the session?

I could find no documentation about it - only that the `session.id` seems to come from engine.io.

Comment: in all the apps I've made sharing the id hasn't caused any issues with hijacking as I'm pretty sure its all assigned by the handshake and is bound to the current socket connection if the connection drops it gets a new id, I'm pretty sure passing the `?sid=` won't hijack the session but is a good point.. you could avoid all issues by making a derivative map of the ids and share that instead, this way ids are not associated with the connection

Comment: a little example of said mapping https://playcode.io/705612/

Comment: yeah, I was also thinking about the map... but if I cannot expose them , I'd probably rather send an encrypted hash of it and decrypt it. This way scaling the app to multiple server would be a bit easier. Otherwise I'd have to put that map also in a redis, like socket.io is doing it with the rooms...